# Scaling of data and predicting new values in R

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, predict

I've been stuck on a problem for a while now and I can't seem to figure out exactly how to solve it.

Introduction:
I'm working on a regression where I predict the proportion of sexual brood produced brood in ant colonies based on several ecological parameters (such as colony size, worker and queen inbreeding, denoted as HL_Q and HL_Colony in the model). The response variable are both numbers of sexual pupae and worker pupae.

```
m_sexual_binom = glmer(cbind(Sexualpupae, Workers)~ scale(HL_Q) + scale(HL_Colony) + scale(Colony_size) + 
                     Island + (1|Colony), data = mergeddata, family = "binomial")
```

As you can see I've scaled all the numeric variables. I guess the first question is whether this is the right way to do it or should I scale each predictor according to the same center?

When I analyse the summary data, I can see that colony size is a highly significant predictor, so I would like to plot the proportion of sexual brood ~ Colony size.

This is where I run into troubles. I first made a new dataset, where I keep the values of all the other predictors at the mean, so that I can use the predict function (for the factors I took a random colony and Island).

```
newdata = data.frame(HL_Q = mean(mergeddata$HL_Q, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 HL_Colony = mean(mergeddata$HL_Colony, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 Colony= "J24", 
                 Island = "Joskär", 
                 Colony_size = mergeddata$Colony_size)
```

Then I use the predict function to predict values of Y for different values of colony size.

```
newdata$y = predict(m_sexual_binom, newdata = newdata, type = "response")
```

I would like to plot this data. The following is only one version of the many things I tried. Sexuals is calculated as the proportion of sexual brood relative to the total brood.

```
plot(Sexuals~scale(Colony_size), data = mergeddata)
lines(newdata$y ~ scale(newdata$Colony_size))
```

What I'm stuck with is:
 - Should Colony_size already be scaled in the newdata data.frame, or should the predict function get non-scaled predictors like here?
 - Both when I scale and don't scale Colony_size in the new data, the graph is not correct. I do not get the S-curve that a logistic regression should produce.

I hope my question is clear. I'd be happy to provide more information if needed.
Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: first question is probably better suited to stats stack exchange site (crossvalidated)

Comment: In terms of scaling your features, here's how I do it: I perform gaussian normalization on my training set (minus mean divide sd) usually within cv folds. When running the predict function on unseen data, you should normalize using means and SD's calculated on the training set. You don't want to normalize all your data in a single go as this is a classic data leakage (scaling train & test data at the same time).